# is app.config file in WinForms cached by .Net framework?

Tags: c#, app-config

I was wondering if someone can confirm that App.Config file is cached by CLR in the AppDomain and not read everytime you try to read the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is loaded at start-up. Reads will reflect whatever the app.config file said at that point.

Comment: Correct. And any changes happening to the actual file, they don't reflect upon the executed application.

Comment: Yes, I should have added that. Thank you.