# App Config Modification not reflected in code

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have a appsetting section in appconfig file  as

```
<appSettings>    
  <add key="DayTime" value="08-20"/>
  <add key="NightTime" value="20-08"/>
</appSettings>
```

I am tyring to modify the app config while application is running. I changed key `DayTime` to 11-20 while application is running.

Now if I run this code again to fetch data from config, it shows previous set values.

```
private void btnDayNightSettings_ShowingEditor(object sender, ItemCancelEventArgs e)
{
     string[] strDayTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DayTime"].Split('-');
}
```

Why it is so ?

Answer (score 14):

The reason behind why the `AppSetting section` in `app.config` file is not getting reflected during update in Run time is as follows:

- When you add a new app.config file it actually creates a file in the local system.
- When you compile it, actually it creates the necessary files including `.Exe` files in `Debug/Release` folder; depending upon the Build mode.
- After successful build it also generates a `.config` file which looks like `YourApplicationName.exe.config` which holds the same entries in original app.config file. And the `.Exe` always refers to this file.
- So whenever you edit the `app.config` at Runtime it actually updates the file but changes are not updated in `YourApplicationName.exe.config` file as it has not re-build yet.

So every time you need to re-build to your app to reflect the changes.

Comment: Wracked my head for hours..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I have my own answer. Just need to refresh `appSettings` section as

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: @phillyd It will only work for release version of your application.

Answer (score 2):

app.config is cached, the changes will reflect when you restart the application. See [is app.config file in WinForms cached by .Net framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822225/is-app-config-file-in-winforms-cached-by-net-framework)

Comment: Cool, learned new thing today. But I am trying to think of scenarios when it will be practically useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string strDayTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DayTime"];

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DayTime", "11-20");

strDayTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DayTime"];
```

The value of the strDayTime variables changes on both lines.