# VB.net app doesn't update the connection string after changing the app.config file

Tags: vb.net

I have done a windows application using vb.net and have set the connection string to be read from the app.config file. everything works fine, but when I try to change the connection string in the app.config file ( for example to change the database location) the application can't find the database anymore.
is there a problem or am I missing something related the connection strings. thank you

Comment: If the application can't find the database you specify then that database doesn't exist. Specify a database that exists and it will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855043/app-config-modification-not-reflected-in-code

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS Access database, you have to specify every database.

```
`<connectionStrings>`      
      <add name="ConnectionString" 
  connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
   Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseName1.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
   </connectionStrings>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseName2.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Also, there is a specific path to every database. The best way is to use the asp.net database folder App_Data and put all databases in this folder.